# Не в курсе как в терминологии, символы \x4F\x4B и т.д. в javascript

Tags: javascript

```
\x4F -> O
\x4B -> K

alert("\x4F\x4B");
```

Кто подсажет полную таблицу символов? Никогда не использовал, но теперь заинтересовался.

Comment: http://ling06.narod.ru/poleznoe/symbols.html - 9999 символов. Грузится долго.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это символы в ashii кодировке. Полная таблица [тут](http://www.industrialnets.ru/index/?node=706).

Comment: Благодарствую, то что нужно было!

Comment: В js не ASCII, а UTF-16. По крайней мере если брать не самые древние реализации, которые не следуют ECMAScript

Answer (score 0):

Это же Юникод там их хренова туча. В js используется  utf-16, причем читал, что часть наиболее употребительных символов использует 8 байт и если не ошибаюсь имеет место полное соотвествие таблице ASCII, а редкие 16 байт из всей таблицы UTF-16. По-этому имеет место неоднородность выделения памяти под строку. И в принципе, виндовая таблица сиволов содержит коды UTF

Comment: Преобразовал в ответ, так же полезная инфа!